# Return element of one list based on true index of another

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a function that returns the indexes for all values that are true for the condition:

```
def check(samples_avg):
    out = [[] for _ in samples_avg]
    for indx, v in enumerate(zip(*samples_avg)):
        m = max((val, i, indx) for i, val in enumerate(v))
        if all(val * 5 < m[0] for i, val in enumerate(v) if i != m[1]):
            out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])
    print (out)
```

so for input: `samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]`
the function returns `out = [[], [0], [1, 2]]`

However, I would like to add the ability for this function to return the element in a different list that is at the true index in the first list analyzed. So for example, for this list:

```
tracker = [['meow', 'woof', 'quack'], ['where', 'what', 'who'], ['dont', 'call', 'me']]
```

I'd expect an output like:

```
[[], ['where'], ['call', 'me']]
```

Because for `samples_avg` out was `out = [[], [0], [1, 2]]`, or true at index 0 in the second list and indexes 2 and 3 in the last list (the first list is empty because nothing was true in it).

To do this I rewrote the function to look like this:

```
def check(samples_avg, tracker):
    out = [[] for _ in samples_avg]
    for indx, v in enumerate(zip(*samples_avg)):
        m = max((val, i, indx) for i, val in enumerate(v))
        if all(val * 5 < m[0] for i, val in enumerate(v) if i != m[1]):
            out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])

            g = [[] for _ in out]
            for f in enumerate(zip(*out)):
               g.append[enumerate(zip(out[f], tracker))]
    print (out)
    print (g)
```

However, this only returns

```
 out = [[], [0], [1, 2]] 
 g = [[], [], []]
```

Any advice on how to fix this so it returns the values as expected would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're reassigning `g` every time through the inner loop. You should initialize it at the top, just like `out`.

Comment: Why are you setting the list `g` every iteration of the first `for` loop?

Comment: BTW, your functions don't **return** anything, they just print things.

Comment: The `for f` loop doesn't make sense to me. `enumerate()` returns tuples, you can't use them as indexes.

Comment: `x.extend([y])` can be written more simply as `x.append(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Your main loop can fill in `out` as you already do. Then you can use a list comprehension to create the corresponding `g` list after the loop is done.

```
g = [[t[i] for i in o] for t, o in zip(tracker, out)]
```

Comment: I tried it with the given lists and got the desired result.

Comment: The values in `out` are indices.